# String inside UIWebView

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

I'm currently working on a app for iOS and I'm having a problem.

My project consists of 2 view controllers. In the first one you enter your text and then press a button that is supposed to transfer the info to the second view controller. In the second one there's a UIWebView item.

I'm trying in the first VC to have a text field were I enter the URL and when I press the button it transfers it to a variable of the second VC where that URL is going to be displayed as a webpage.

Code for first VC:

```
@IBOutlet weak var linkfield: UITextField!

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let DestViewController2 : ViewController2 = segue.destination as! ViewController2

    DestViewController2.texto = linkfield.text!
}
```

And the code for the second VC is:

```
var texto = String()

@IBOutlet weak var web: UIWebView!
```

I want to have the link in the string "texto" and then "texto" (that is supposed to be a URL) to be displayed on the UIWebView.

Comment: You should include what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

in `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear`, try loading the URL string as URL:

```
    web.delegate = self // in Onalod
    let url  = URL.init(string:urlString!) // from first VC
    let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url!)
    web.loadRequest(urlRequest)
```

> make the controller inherit from UIWebViewDelegate along with
>   UIViewController.

Comment: It tells me  web.loadRequest(urlRequest) expected declaration